# Biblatex indentation second line

Tags: biblatex, citing

I was using the environment `\begin{thebibliography}` before to list

it looks like this:
[image]

I just want to have a .bib file for the references that I always cite. So I use BibLaTeX and `\printbibliography`. But it becomes like this:

[image]

How to set so that the second line and hereafter also starts from the beginning of the line (, and with a small space), not just after the label like the first one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that by locally setting `\labelwidth` to 0 in the bibliography environment (and by adjusting `\biblabelsep`).

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=alphabetic]{biblatex}

\setlength{\biblabelsep}{\labelsep}
\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\list
     {\printtext[labelalphawidth]{%
        \printfield{labelprefix}%
        \printfield{labelalpha}%
        \printfield{extraalpha}}}
     {\setlength{\labelwidth}{0pt}%
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
      \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
      \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}%
      \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{##1\hss}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson,nussbaum,geer,worman}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: [Gee85] Ingrid de Geer. ‘Earl, Saint, Bishop, Skald – and Music. The Orkney Earldom of the Twelfth Century. A Musicological Study’. PhD thesis. Uppsala: Uppsala Universitet, 1985. [Nus78] Martha Nussbaum. Aristotle’s ‘De Motu Animalium’. Princeton: Princeton University Press, 1978. [SR98] Emma Sigfridsson and Ulf Ryde. ‘Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the electrostatic potential and moments’. In: Journal of Computational Chemistry 19.4 (1998), pp. 377–395. doi: 10.1002/(SICI)1096-987X(199803)19:4<377::AID-JCC1>3.0.CO;2-P. [Wor02] Nancy Worman. The Cast of Character. Style in Greek Literature. Austin: University of Texas Press, 2002.]

I don't think this is particular readable, though. In all cases that I have BibTeX seen generate output like this that was because the document did not load a support package in a way the `.bst` file expected.

Comment: @CO2 I agree, It's better as it comes by default, but anyway I wouldn't use alphabetic style even being threatened to listen six hours of reggaeton.